# How can i redirect a specific link with a chrome extension

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, http-redirect, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

When trying to redirect a link for example "https://instagram.com/reels" with a manifest 3 chrome extension, the link is always redirected when I directly open the page. However when I click the reels button on instagram, the link changes but does not redirect. How can i make the link always redirect. (first stackoverflow post, hope I did this correctly)

Json manifest

```
{
    "name": "A",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "B",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "C",
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules1.json"
      }
    ]
  },
    "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback",
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://www.instagram.com/",
    "https://developer.chrome.com/"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.instagram.com/",
        "https://www.youtube.com/"

      ],
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Json file rules1

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "redirect",
      "redirect": {
        "url": "https://www.instagram.com"
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "https://www.instagram.com/reels/*",
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This site is faking intra-site navigation via `history.pushState`, so there's no network request, hence you can't redirect it via declarative**Net**Request.

To account for this case try using [navigation.onnavigate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation/navigate_event) event listener in your content script to intercept the URL as shown in the linked article and then redirect it via `location.href = '/'`

Warning! Make your content script's `matches` cover the entire site: `https://www.instagram.com/*`